# ¿Cómo usar triggers afectando tablas relacionadas usando PL/SQL en Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, base-de-datos, plsql

Tengo problemas con el uso de TRIGGERS en el lenguaje PL/SQL justo en oracle 11g. Lo que pasa es que tengo 3 tablas que están relacionadas. Éstas son:

- Alumnos
- Matricula
- Curso

Lo que tengo que realizar es que cuando elimino un alumno, también se elimine su matricula y sus cursos. Tengo el siguiente codigo.

```sql
create or replace trigger eliminardata
before delete on alumnos
for each row
declare
  num number;
begin
  select numatri into num from matricula;
  delete from matricula where codigo=codigo;
  dbms_output.put_line('CODIGO MATRICULA');
  dbms_output.put_line(:old.codigo||' '||num);
end;

delete from alumnos where codigo = 'A001';
```

Necesito su ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Mejor habilita el borrado en cascada. O mejor aún: **no lo borres en absoluto** y utiliza un borrado lógico. Agrega una columna que sea estado donde lo actualizas a *Eliminado* o similar de manera que no se elimina la información de dicho alumno.

Comment: Hasta ahora cambie la logica y hasta este momento ya me elimina el alumno y su matricula pero me falta la nota, la nota esta relacionada con la tabla matricula y no con la tabla alumno

create or replace trigger eliminaralumno
before delete on alumnos
for each row
begin
 delete from matricula where CODIGO=:old.CODIGO;
end;

delete from alumnos where CODIGO = 'A009';

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el borrado en cascada en el constraints; aquí un ejemplo en donde hago referencia a la tabla `M_USER` con un `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE D_INFO_NOT ADD (
  CONSTRAINT FK_D_INFO_NOT 
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_M_USER) 
  REFERENCES M_USER(ID_M_USER)
  **ON DELETE CASCADE**
  ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Dices que la tabla nota esta relacionada con matricula. asi que deberia ser algo asi:

```
create or replace trigger eliminardata
before delete on alumnos
for each row
declare
  num number;
begin
  select numatri into num from matricula;
  --Crea un ciclo para buscar las matriculas del estudiante y asi lanzar un  
  --delete para todas las notas(no se si sea el esquema correcto)
  for reg in (select * from nota where codigo=:old.codigo) loop
      DELETE NOTA WHERE ID_mATRICULA = REG.id_MATRICULA AND codigo=:old.codigo;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('CODIGO MATRICULA');
  dbms_output.put_line(:old.codigo||' '||num);
  --por ultimo elimina el codigo de la tabla matricula
  delete from matricula where codigo=:old.codigo;
end;
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo no hacer borrados físicos, si no borrados lógicos. Nota: por favor coloca siempre el esquema de las tablas para poder ayudarte con el query